# What's the recommended oem partition size for an Android Things product?

Tags: android-things, android-things-console

While creating another Android Things product with the Android Things Console i've been wondering again what oem partition size to choose. The info for this setting is *"Must be between 32 and 512 MB"* which is quite a range to consider. 
While my apk-file in Android Studio is only around  100KB and would fit easily into the minimum size of 32MB. I searched the net and stackoverflow for a while but couldn't come up with reasonable info. I figure the apk-size gets much bigger maybe if i add a lot of resources, images and so on to my app or am i missing something?

Therefore i'd like to know if there are any recommendations for the oem partition size?  Are there any drawbacks to always select 256M or 512M just to be on the safe side?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The partition size you select should be large enough to account for growth in your APK over the lifecycle of your product, as it cannot be changed once you start deploying over the air (OTA) updates.

The storage space allocated for your apps is essentially shared with user data, so allocating more space than you need for apps means you'll have less space for the files/databases associated with those apps. So find the right balance that works for your device.

Comment: well, thank you. finding the right balance probably is the challenge here. Though i checked the size of the apps on my smart phone and not even the largest ones exceed 100M. So i think i'm going to stick to the minimum size of 32M or 64M while still wondering what kind of android things app would use up to 500M. But surely there are some cool iot apps  to come in the future.